# MP3 Player in Qt in C++ (Cross Platform)

Tags: mp3, playback

I am currently looking to create a basic MP3 player in Qt for my university project. I am struggling to find an example of how to create the code, any advice on how to create the program?

thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 1):

I find the Qt site is quite messy for search different versions of samples to download, but you can find lots of samples in the Welcome tab of Qt creator. Type 'media' then you can check them out. Start from Audio Output Example & Media Player Example.

[image: media samples in the Qt creator]